# c# & MYSQL Mandar valor null en procedimiento almacenado

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedure, null, visual-studio-2019

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en mysql que funciona correctamente desde worbench:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `select_patching`(in building varchar(30),in floor varchar(30),
in closet varchar(30),in panel varchar(30),in port_panel varchar(30))
BEGIN

/* Si ningun campo es null (building nunca lo es por eso no se parameteriza)*/
if floor IS NOT NULL  and closet IS NOT NULL and panel IS NOT NULL and port_panel IS NOT NULL then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"' and floor = '",floor,"' and closet = '",closet,"' 
and panel = '",panel,"' and Panel_port = '",port_panel,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;

/* si el campo port panel es null */
if floor IS NOT NULL  and closet IS NOT NULL and panel IS NOT NULL and port_panel IS NULL then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"' and floor = '",floor,"' and closet = '",closet,"' 
and panel = '",panel,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;

/* si el campo PANEL  es null */
if floor IS NOT NULL  and closet IS NOT NULL and panel IS NULL then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"' and floor = '",floor,"' 
and closet = '",closet,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;

/* si el campo CLOSET es null */
if floor IS NOT NULL  and closet IS NULL then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"' and 
floor = '",floor,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;

/* si el campo FLOOR es null */
if floor IS NULL  then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;
END
```

El cual invoco desde worbench de la siguiente forma, la cual funciona correctamente:

```
call select_patchingV2('barcelona',null,null,null,null)
```

El problema viene cuando invoco el procedure desde C#,
parece que no manda los valores "null", 
los valores son recogidos de varios textbox que están de la siguiente manera
Ya que los campos cuando tienen valor necesitan ser convertidos en string:

```
            string building = comboBoxBuilding.Text.ToString();
            string floor = textBoxFloor.Text.ToString();
            string closet = textBoxCloset.Text.ToString();
            string panel = textBoxPanel.Text.ToString();
            string port_panel = textBoxPortPanel.Text.ToString();
            bool Vbuilding = Common.ValidadorCamposVacios_SinMensaje(building);


            if (Vbuilding == true)
            {
                mysql_commmands.Select_patching(building, floor, closet, panel, port_panel, dataGridView_patching);
            }
```

También he probado esto:

```
string floor = null;
            string closet = null;
            string panel = null;
            string port_panel = null;

            if (textBoxFloor.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                floor = textBoxFloor.Text.ToString();
            }
            if (textBoxCloset.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                closet = textBoxCloset.Text.ToString();
            }
            if (textBoxPanel.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                panel = textBoxPanel.Text.ToString();
            }
            if (textBoxPortPanel.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                port_panel = textBoxPortPanel.Text.ToString();
            }
            string building = comboBoxBuilding.Text.ToString();
            /*
            string floor = textBoxFloor.Text.ToString();
            string closet = textBoxCloset.Text.ToString();
            string panel = textBoxPanel.Text.ToString();
            string port_panel = textBoxPortPanel.Text.ToString();
            */
            bool Vbuilding = Common.ValidadorCamposVacios_SinMensaje(building);


            if (Vbuilding == true)
            {
                Sentencias.Select_patching(building, floor, closet, panel, port_panel, dataGridView_patching);
            }
```

Luego invoco el procedure con los siguientes metodos:

```
  public static void Select_patching(string building,string floor,string closet,string panel,string panel_port, DataGridView Datagrid_Name)
        {
            string query = "call select_patching('" + building + "','" + floor + "','" + closet + "','" + panel + "','" + panel_port + "')";
            Bbdd_simply_all_datagridView("patching", query, Datagrid_Name);
        }
```

Que se ejecuta en el metodo:

```
  public static void Bbdd_simply_all_datagridView(string tabla, string query, DataGridView Datagrid_Name)
        {
            MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(bbdd_connection_data());
            databaseConnection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter commandDatabase = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, databaseConnection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            commandDatabase.Fill(ds, tabla);
            Datagrid_Name.DataSource = ds;
            Datagrid_Name.DataMember = tabla;
            databaseConnection.Close();
        }
```

El caso es, que he encontrado ejemplos para SQL SERVER, pero nada para mysql, o estoy equivocado en el concepto, o estoy cometiendo un error de bulto.
Desde c# solo funciona cuando ningún campo es null, y desde mysql funciona todo correctamente.

¿Podria alguien decirme cual es la forma en la que se puede realizar?

un cordial saludo.

Comment: ¿Has probado a la hora de asignar tus valores _building, floor, ..._ de poner un `if-else` donde asignas un **null** a la variable cuando el contenido está vacio, es decir es igual a **""**?

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte de tu código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me parece que no tendrías que colocar .ToString() en los valores que quieres que te devuelvan null.

Comment: Pero es que esos valores, pueden tener contenido del tipo string, lo que necesito es que cuando no tengan contenido, el valor que se envie a MYSQL sea de tipo null.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es pasar un *null* a tu función, deberías hacer algo de este estilo:

```
string building = null;
string floor = null;
...

if (comboBoxBuilding.Text.length>0)
{
    building = comboBoxBuilding.Text.ToString()
}

if (textBoxFloor.Text.ToString() <> "")
{
    floor = textBoxFloor.Text.ToString();
}

...
```

Nota: Te he puesto 2 formas diferentes de saber si un *String* está vacío. Hay más modos de mirarlo. VS Te suele sugerir usar la primera forma.

Te añado también el cambio necesario en tu función `Select_Patching` para tener en cuenta esos valores `null`.

```
public static void Select_patching(string building, string floor, String closet, string panel, string panel_port, DataGridView Datagrid_Name)
{
    if (floor == null) 
        floor ="null" /* simplemente un null en la sentencia SQL */
    else 
        floor ="'" + floor + "'" /* El valor del string entre comillas */

    if (closet == null) 
        closet ="null" /* simplemente un null en la sentencia SQL */
    else 
        closet ="'" + closet + "'" /* El valor del string entre comillas */

    if (panel == null) 
        panel ="null" /* simplemente un null en la sentencia SQL */
    else 
        panel ="'" + panel + "'" /* El valor del string entre comillas */

    if (panel_port == null) 
        panel_port ="null" /* simplemente un null en la sentencia SQL */
    else 
        panel_port ="'" + panel_port + "'" /* El valor del string entre comillas */

    /* IMPORTANTE: las comillas ya las ponemos antes para diferenciar 
       un string de un null en tu PROCEDURE. 
       No olvides tenerlo en cuenta al construir ahora tu string 'query'
    */

    string query = "call select_patching('" + building + "'," + floor + "," + closet + "," + panel + "," + panel_port + ")";
    Bbdd_simply_all_datagridView("patching", query, Datagrid_Name);
}
```

Comment: No funciona. Lo he probado también.
Te añado el codigo basado en tu supuesto:

Comment: No te funciona haciendo : `mysql_commmands.Select_patching(building, floor, closet, panel, port_panel, dataGridView_patching);` y el código que te he pasado y si te funciona haciedo, por ejemplo: `mysql_commmands.Select_patching(building, null, null, null, null, dataGridView_patching);` ????  o haciendolo directamente, tampoco te funciona?...

Comment: no funciona desde c# de ninguna de las formas.
Ese es el problema que estoy encontrando, por alguna razón c# no manda valores null a MYSQL.

Tu ejemplo segundo estaba incorrecto, la forma es != en lugar de <>

He visto que para sql server se usa DB.NULL o similar, pero para mysql no encuentro nada.

Comment: Ya he visto donde tienes el problema... en la función select_patching... te hago una respuesta nueva y te quitaré está después, aunque parte de la misma es necesaria... Unos minutos ....

Comment: No funciona tampoco, en internet encontre esto:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/a228ea0b-a8bb-4749-8147-2d7aa9818f95/mandar-campo-null-a-base-de-datos-sql?forum=vbes

La propiedad :
System.DBNull.Value para sqlserver

Lo que creo que debe ser la clave es lo mismo para Mysql.
Es lo que ando buscando, el metodo equivalente.

Muchas gracias por intentar ayudarme pero no hay manera...

Comment: No, ya que tu no usas objetos procedentes de la BD con valor null, sino que usas un string para ejecutar una secuencia SQL.  Verifica que no pones el valor null que te pongo entre comillas en el string que montas... te lo he comentado en el código.

Comment: Como te comenté antes.... no funciona.
Estoy buscando alternativas, si encuentro la respuesta la pondré aqui.

Answer (score 0):

No he encontrado solucion, pero si he encontrado otra forma de que la funcionalidad funcione:
He añadido una nueva variable "tipo_consulta int(10)" al procedure, y con el sql dinamico le indico desde el codigo que consulta realizar.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `select_patching`(in building varchar(30),in floor varchar(30),
in closet varchar(30),in panel varchar(30),in port_panel varchar(30), in tipo_consulta int(10))
BEGIN
/* Si ningun campo es null (building nunca lo es por eso no se parameteriza)*/
if tipo_consulta = '1' then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"' and floor = '",floor,"' and closet = '",closet,"' 
and panel = '",panel,"' and Panel_port = '",port_panel,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;
/* si el campo port panel es null */
if tipo_consulta = '2' then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"' and floor = '",floor,"' and closet = '",closet,"' 
and panel = '",panel,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;
/* si el campo PANEL  es null */
if tipo_consulta = '3' then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"' and floor = '",floor,"' 
and closet = '",closet,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;

/* si el campo CLOSET es null */
if tipo_consulta = '4' then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"' and 
floor = '",floor,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;

/* si el campo FLOOR es null */
if tipo_consulta = '5' then
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM npms.patching where Building = '",building,"';");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;
END
```

Y en select patching he hecho lo siguiente:

```
        public static void Select_patching(string building,string floor,string closet,string panel,string port_panel, DataGridView Datagrid_Name)
        {


            bool Vfloor = Common.ValidadorCamposVacios_SinMensaje(floor);
            bool Vcloset = Common.ValidadorCamposVacios_SinMensaje(closet);
            bool Vpanel = Common.ValidadorCamposVacios_SinMensaje(panel);
            bool Vport_panel = Common.ValidadorCamposVacios_SinMensaje(port_panel);

            // si todos los campos son true
            if (Vfloor == true && Vcloset == true && Vpanel == true && Vport_panel == true)
            {
                int TipoConsulta = 1;
                string query = "call select_patching('" + building + "','" + floor + "','" + closet + "','" + panel + "','" + port_panel + "','" + TipoConsulta + "')";
                Bbdd_simply_all_datagridView("patching", query, Datagrid_Name);
            }
            // si port_panel es false y lo demas es true
            if (Vfloor == true && Vcloset == true && Vpanel == true && Vport_panel == false)
            {
                int TipoConsulta = 2;
                string query = "call select_patching('" + building + "','" + floor + "','" + closet + "','" + panel + "','" + port_panel + "','" + TipoConsulta + "')";
                Bbdd_simply_all_datagridView("patching", query, Datagrid_Name);
            }
            //si el campo panel es false y lo demas true
            if (Vfloor == true && Vcloset == true && Vpanel == false)
            {
                int TipoConsulta = 3;
                string query = "call select_patching('" + building + "','" + floor + "','" + closet + "','" + panel + "','" + port_panel + "','" + TipoConsulta + "')";
                Bbdd_simply_all_datagridView("patching", query, Datagrid_Name);
            }
            //si el campo closet es null y lo demas true
            if (Vfloor == true && Vcloset == false)
            {
                int TipoConsulta = 4;
                string query = "call select_patching('" + building + "','" + floor + "','" + closet + "','" + panel + "','" + port_panel + "','" + TipoConsulta + "')";
                Bbdd_simply_all_datagridView("patching", query, Datagrid_Name);
            }
            //si el campo floor es null
            if (Vfloor == false)
            {
                int TipoConsulta = 5;
                string query = "call select_patching('" + building + "','" + floor + "','" + closet + "','" + panel + "','" + port_panel + "','" + TipoConsulta + "')";
                Bbdd_simply_all_datagridView("patching", query, Datagrid_Name);
            }         
        }
```